# How to solve module 'pandas' has no attribute 'scatter_matrix' attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

this is the code which i used but it is giving me the error even after importing scatter_matrix :

```
from matplotlib import cm
    from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
    X = fruits[['height', 'width', 'mass', 'color_score']]
    y = fruits['fruit_label']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
    
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
    scatter = pd.scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
```

Comment: a few suggestions: 1) make the code runnable by others; `fruits` is not defined in your snippet. 2) copy the error message that is produced.

A guess: the code is improperly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your formatting is okay you can try dropping the `pd.scatter_matrix` and just keeping `scatter_matrix`

```
scatter = pd.scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
```

into

```
scatter = scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
```

you also might need to add matplotlib inline for your notebook if you using jupyter notebook

```
%matplotlib notebook

from matplotlib import cm
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
    
X = fruits[['height', 'width', 'mass', 'color_score']]
y = fruits['fruit_label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
        
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
scatter = scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is under `pandas.plotting`, try using [`pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html)

```py
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

fruits = pd.DataFrame("...")

X = fruits[["height", "width", "mass", "color_score"]]
y = fruits["fruit_label"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

cmap = cm.get_cmap("gnuplot")
scatter = scatter_matrix(
    X_train,
    c=y_train,
    marker="o",
    s=40,
    hist_kwds={"bins": 15},
    figsize=(9, 9),
    cmap=cmap,
)
```